# Issues Deserializing complex XML into objects C# .NET Core 6 MVC Web App with API controller

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core-mvc, deserialization, asp.net-core-webapi

This will be a long question as there is a lot of code to show to determine what the root cause of the problem is and for others to be able to run the code to help solve the issue.

The issue that I am having is that when I deserialize the XML (using `XmlReader` and `XmlSerializer`), all the objects are there and the hierarchy is correct, but all the values are null or default (for numerical types).

The users of the application download Rubrics they have created from Blackboard (Learning Management System), which exports them as standard binary stream files (.dat), and then they upload that file to my MVC Web Application.

Here is an example of the XML contained within one of these files, and the example that I have been using to debug the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LEARNRUBRICS>
  <Rubric id="_24301_1">
    <Title value="Lesson 10 Assignment"/>
    <Description value="Students are solving the kth smallest algorithm problem and implementing a Java solution to it."/>
    <ContactName value=""/>
    <Version value="1"/>
    <CreatorId value="_73949_1"/>
    <Type value="NUMERIC"/>
    <Status value="ACTIVE"/>
    <Public value="false"/>
    <DeletedIndicator value="false"/>
    <MaxValue value="100.00000"/>
    <Keywords value=""/>
    <DATES>
        <CREATED value="2022-06-25 09:04:39 EDT"/>
        <UPDATED value="2022-06-25 09:04:39 EDT"/>
    </DATES>
    <RubricRows>
        <Row id="_104569_1">
            <Header value="grid.row1.label"/>
            <Position value="0"/>
            <Percentage value="15.000000000000000"/>
            <RubricColumns>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column1.label"/>
                    <Position value="0"/>
                    <Cell id="_382286_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Did novice work for formatting"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="2.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="13.333330000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column2.label"/>
                    <Position value="1"/>
                    <Cell id="_382287_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Did competent work for formatting"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="4.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="26.666660000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column3.label"/>
                    <Position value="2"/>
                    <Cell id="_382288_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Proficient work for formatting"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="8.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="53.333330000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="Expert"/>
                    <Position value="3"/>
                    <Cell id="_382289_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Expert work for formatting"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="15.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="100.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
            </RubricColumns>
        </Row>
        <Row id="_104570_1">
            <Header value="grid.row2.label"/>
            <Position value="1"/>
            <Percentage value="20.000000000000000"/>
            <RubricColumns>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column1.label"/>
                    <Position value="0"/>
                    <Cell id="_382290_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Did novice work for organization"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="5.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="25.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column2.label"/>
                    <Position value="1"/>
                    <Cell id="_382291_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Did competent work for organization"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="10.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="50.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column3.label"/>
                    <Position value="2"/>
                    <Cell id="_382292_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Proficient work for organization"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="15.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="75.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="Expert"/>
                    <Position value="3"/>
                    <Cell id="_382293_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Expert work for organization"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="20.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="100.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
            </RubricColumns>
        </Row>
        <Row id="_104571_1">
            <Header value="grid.row3.label"/>
            <Position value="2"/>
            <Percentage value="20.000000000000000"/>
            <RubricColumns>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column1.label"/>
                    <Position value="0"/>
                    <Cell id="_382294_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Did novice work for Grammar"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="7.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="35.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column2.label"/>
                    <Position value="1"/>
                    <Cell id="_382295_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Did competent work for Grammar"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="12.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="60.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column3.label"/>
                    <Position value="2"/>
                    <Cell id="_382296_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Proficient work for Grammar"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="16.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="80.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="Expert"/>
                    <Position value="3"/>
                    <Cell id="_382297_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Expert work for Grammar"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="20.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="100.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
            </RubricColumns>
        </Row>
        <Row id="_104572_1">
            <Header value="Syntax"/>
            <Position value="3"/>
            <Percentage value="35.000000000000000"/>
            <RubricColumns>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column1.label"/>
                    <Position value="0"/>
                    <Cell id="_382298_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Did novice work for Syntax"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="5.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="14.285710000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column2.label"/>
                    <Position value="1"/>
                    <Cell id="_382299_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Did competent work for Syntax"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="15.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="42.857140000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column3.label"/>
                    <Position value="2"/>
                    <Cell id="_382300_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Proficient work for Syntax"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="25.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="71.428570000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="Expert"/>
                    <Position value="3"/>
                    <Cell id="_382301_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Expert work for Syntax"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="35.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="100.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax  value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
            </RubricColumns>
        </Row>
        <Row id="_104573_1">
            <Header value="Detail"/>
            <Position value="4"/>
            <Percentage value="10.000000000000000"/>
            <RubricColumns>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column1.label"/>
                    <Position value="0"/>
                    <Cell id="_382302_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Did novice work for Detail"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="2.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="20.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column2.label"/>
                    <Position value="1"/>
                    <Cell id="_382303_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Did competent work for Detail"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="4.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="40.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="grid.column3.label"/>
                    <Position value="2"/>
                    <Cell id="_382304_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Proficient work for Detail"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="8.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="80.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Header value="Expert"/>
                    <Position value="3"/>
                    <Cell id="_382305_1">
                        <CellDescription value="Expert work for Detail"/>
                        <NumericPoints value="10.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericStartPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <NumericEndPointRange value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentage value="100.000000000000000"/>
                        <PercentageMax value="0.000000000000000"/>
                        <Percentagemin value="0.000000000000000"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Column>
            </RubricColumns>
        </Row>
    </RubricRows>
   </Rubric>
 </LEARNRUBRICS>
```

Since I am using `XmlReader` and `XmlSerializer` to deserialize this XML into objects, I have created models for those objects specifically for the deserialization, so that I can then create the corresponding database entity models and save them to the database. Here are the deserialization models I have created, starting from the `XmlRootElement` `LEARNRUBRICS` object:

LEARNRUBRICS Class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace RiverhawkRubric.Models.DeserializationModels;

[Serializable, XmlRoot("LEARNRUBRICS")]
public class LEARNRUBRICS
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Rubric Rubric { get; set; }

    public LEARNRUBRICS() { }
}
```

Rubric Class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace RiverhawkRubric.Models.DeserializationModels;

[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class Rubric
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Public { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool DeletedIndicator { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double MaxValue { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<DateTime> DATES { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public RubricRows RubricRows { get; set; }

    public Rubric() { }
}
```

RubricRows Class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace RiverhawkRubric.Models.DeserializationModels;

[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class RubricRows
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Row[] Row { get; set; }
}
```

Row Class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace RiverhawkRubric.Models.DeserializationModels;

[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class Row
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Header{ get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Position { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double Percentage { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public RubricColumns RubricColumns { get; set; }

    public Row() { } 
}
```

RubricColumns Class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace RiverhawkRubric.Models.DeserializationModels;

[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class RubricColumns
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Column[] Column { get; set; }

    public RubricColumns() { }
}
```

Cloumn Class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace RiverhawkRubric.Models.DeserializationModels;

[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class Column
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Header { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Position { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Cell Cell { get; set; }

    public Column() { }
}
```

Cell Class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace RiverhawkRubric.Models.DeserializationModels;

[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class Cell
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string CellDescription { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double NumericPoints { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double NumericStartPointRange { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double NumericEndPointRange { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double Percentage { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double PercentageMax { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double Percentagemin { get; set; }

    public Cell() { }
}
```

The user uses a standard form to upload the file to the API controller.

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Upload Rubric";
}

<div class="text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4">Upload Rubric</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="UploadRubric" asp-action="Upload">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Upload Rubric</label>
            <input type="file" name="rubric" class="form-control"/>
        </div>    
        <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I pass the file to the API controller as an `IFormFile` and begin processing it. I check to ensure it is one of two file types (.dat and .xml) and that it is not an empty file and if it meets both criteria I pass it on to be deserialized.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(406)]
[ProducesResponseType(422)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm]IFormFile rubric)
{
    //check file is valid file type and not empty file
    if (!IsValidFileFormat(rubric))
    {
        //if file is not .dat or .xml return 422 Unprocessable Entity
        return UnprocessableEntity();
    }
    else if(rubric.Length <= 0)
    {
        //if empty file return 411 Length Required
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status411LengthRequired);
    }
    bool successful = false;

    // deserialize XmlDocument object to db objects and save to db
    successful = DeserializeXml(rubric);
    if (successful)
    {
        // if deserialization was successful return 200 with XML content
        return Ok(/*rubricXml.OuterXml*/);
    }
    else
    {
        // if deserialization was not successful return 500 Internal Server Error
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError) ;
    }
  
}
```

Then in the `DeserializeXml(IFormFile rubric)` method, I create an instance of my root element and then use a MemoryStream to copy the file to, using `XmlReader` and I deserialize it using `XmlSerializer`:

```
private bool DeserializeXml(IFormFile rubric)
{
    try
    {
        LEARNRUBRICS rubricXML = null;
        
        using (MemoryStream stream = new())
        {
            rubric.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LEARNRUBRICS));
            rubricXML = (LEARNRUBRICS)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            stream.Close();
        }

        //I stopped my logic here, so that I can run the app in debug mode
        //Pass it the file and then see what the rubricXML local variable's
        //state is before the return true statement.
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
    }          
}
```

I have a breakpoint set at the `return true;` statement at the end of the `DeserializeXml(IFormFile)` method and when I run the application in debug mode and upload the file, the LEARNRUBRICS deserialized object has all of the child objects populated, the correct number of rows and columns and cells, but all the values are either null or the default.

I know that the XML is complex, as are the deserialized models, but if anyone has any insight as to why this might be happening, please let me know.

Comment: I recommend that you intialize your objects within the classes above. Also use a List instead of an array, and initialize the list(s). Why all the `[XmlIgnore]`? Your XML file seems to contain this data. You may try letting VS create the classes for you. Add a class to your project.  Remove the class code `public class Class1 { }`. Click the cursor inside the class file. Then copy your XML by highlighting it and selecting ctrl-C. Then in VS menu, click Edit => Paste Special => Paste XML as Classes.

Comment: You are probably getting 406,422, or 500 (probably 500) response.  These error codes should be processed in a different method.  500 is a common error which means internal server error.

Comment: @user9938  Yes the XML does contain Attributes for those fields that I have marked with the [XmlIgnore] decorator, but I am not interested in those values. I am aware that unless I have an overloaded parameterized constructor, I don't need to add the default constructor for the XML deserialization as it is there implicitly, was just troubleshooting so I added them. I tried using both the XSD command line utility and the Paste Special -> PasteXML features, but neither worked and they generated extremely complex partial classes that threw exceptions when deserializing.

Comment: @Rena, your solution worked perfectly. I simply had to add the [XmlType] annotation to the MiddleClass class declaration and it deserialized the XML while retaining the values for the attributes. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add a middle class :

```
public class MiddleClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your model (change all the properties declared with `[XmlAttribute]`):

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("LEARNRUBRICS")]
public class LEARNRUBRICS
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Rubric Rubric { get; set; }
    public LEARNRUBRICS() { }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class Rubric
{
    public MiddleClass Title { get; set; }
    public MiddleClass Description { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int Version { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }

    public MiddleClass Type { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Public { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool DeletedIndicator { get; set; }

    public MiddleClass MaxValue { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<DateTime> DATES { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public RubricRows RubricRows { get; set; }

    public Rubric() { }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class RubricRows
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Row[] Row { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class Row
{
    public MiddleClass Header { get; set; }
    public MiddleClass Position { get; set; }
    public MiddleClass Percentage { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public RubricColumns RubricColumns { get; set; }
    public Row() { }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class RubricColumns
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Column[] Column { get; set; }
    public RubricColumns() { }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class Column
{
    public MiddleClass Header { get; set; }
    public MiddleClass Position { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Cell Cell { get; set; }
    public Column() { }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class Cell
{
    public MiddleClass CellDescription { get; set; }
    public MiddleClass NumericPoints { get; set; }
    public MiddleClass NumericStartPointRange { get; set; }
    public MiddleClass NumericEndPointRange { get; set; }
    public MiddleClass Percentage { get; set; }
    public MiddleClass PercentageMax { get; set; }
    public MiddleClass Percentagemin { get; set; }
    public Cell() { }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution solved my issue. The only thing that I had to change was to add the [XmlType] decorator to the MiddleClass declaration. Without that annotation, it throws exceptions trying to reflect the models that have that type as a field. Excellent job, and thanks a million.